# Table cell within JQuery dialog box reduces in size on click

Tags: jquery, jquery-dialog

I have a table that is displayed within a `JQuery` dialog box. The height and width attributes  of the dialog box are set to `auto` and the `autoResize` property is also set.

There is an `onclick` attribute associated with one of the cells in the table. I find that clicking on the cell causes it to reduce in height. Resizing the dialog box removes this effect.

Further, this effect is removed when the height attribute is changed from `auto` to say 150.

How do I prevent this?

The JQuery dialog box:

```
$('#success').dialog({
    height: 'auto',
    width: 'auto',
    modal: true,
    draggable: true,
    resizable: true,
    dialogClass: 'pronounceCSS'
});
```

The table:

```
<div id="success" title="">
    <table id="pronounceTable" width="100%">
        <tr>
            <td class="placeHolder">Word</td>
            <td class="separator"></td>
            <td class="placeHolder">Pronounce</td>
            <td class="button"><button id="close">C</button></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td rowspan="2" id="wordToPronounce" class="pronounceContent">Hahaha</td>
            <td rowspan="2" class="separator"></td>
            <td rowspan="2" id="syllableHolder" class="pronounceContent">HooHoo</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

I have also set up a JSFiddle [here.](http://jsfiddle.net/sriramshankar/83aZ7/)

Answer (score 0):

You have an issue with your table cells matching in your table rows.
I'm not sure exactly what you mean to to, but if you fix the td count to match then the issue should be resolved. Try the following for your div content:

```
<div id="success" title="">
    <table id="pronounceTable" width="100%">
        <tr>
            <td class="placeHolder">Word</td>
            <td class="separator"></td>
            <td class="placeHolder">Pronounce</td>
            <td class="button"><button id="close">C</button></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td id="wordToPronounce" class="pronounceContent">Hahaha</td>
            <td class="separator"></td>
            <td id="syllableHolder" class="pronounceContent">HooHoo</td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

I tested here http://jsfiddle.net/83aZ7/11/ and didn't see any issue. Otherwise include browser type and version if possible.

Comment: Yes. you are right. there was a mismatch in the number of cells on either row. However, that did not solve the problem.